# How can I access the binary format of a file?

Tags: architecture, binary, organization, binary-data

I just finished a computer organization course, in which we learned that all files and data are stored in the form of 0's and 1's (bits).  However, I'm curious how a programmer can actually access a file's binary representation?  That is, how can I see (or access) the 0's and 1's that represent any file on my computer?

Comment: Preferably Java.  I just want to be able to "see" or access the bytes of a file.  This is what they teach us in school, but I want to see the actual 1's and 0's of any file (such as a txt file or an exe file on my computer).

Comment: actually, if you just want to see the file, you should find a hex editor which is program design to look at files that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that at the most basic level, everything is stored as bits, most processors these days only allow you to access bytes (8 bit blocks). From a byte, however, you can figure out if a bit is one or not.

To get the value of a bit in position `pos` (from least significant bit, 0, to most significant bit, 7) of byte `byte`, you could use this code (in C, here, but it's likely valid in many languages):

```
// bit here is likely 32 bits, but it will only contain 0 or 1,
// based on the value of the bit at pos in byte
int bit=(byte>>pos)&1;
```

Comment: But, how can I access the byte? Also, could I use the Java language to do this instead of C?  If I attempt to open a file using Java (e.g. a text file), then I can only parse the actual data in the file (e.g. strings of characters)...but how do I parse the bytes?

Comment: @whistler: Just read the bytes from the file as normal, using [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) or something. The code in my answer should work if you rename `byte` to something else (the name `byte` is reserved in Java).

Comment: @whistler: Oh, and to get all of the bits from a byte, just use the method I posted looping `pos` from 7 to 0, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly read the file character by character, assuming <strike>Java has or treats characters as unsigned</strike> you convert the byte in to an integer - then the decimal value of each byte will be the sum of the specific byte. You can then change its base in to a representable binary form:

```
String byte = Integer.toBinaryString(integer);
```

This should be in the Java package `java.lang` ([toBinaryString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)) and you can loop until the end of file with whichever stream byte wrapper you wish.

**EDIT**:

To provide insight on your question about how programmers read a binary format (although on the low level)

I am unsure of how to do this in Java, although in C you would create a struct (A container of variables) and read bytes directly in to each member, you could assume the file structure beforehand by the defined file type (i.e. read 4 bytes, make float, read n bytes as vector array)